# entity_metadata_wrapper langcode always prints default language

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

I'm using entity_metadata_wrapper with entity translation to print fields in a template, but it always prints the default language when using a langcode in the options.

```
$wrap = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node->nid, array('langcode' => 'zh-hans'));
print $wrap->field_main_subtitle->value(); // Returns English value
```

Printing out the $wrap array shows the following towards the end which might give some clue (langcode:protected => und):

```
[propertyInfoAltered:protected] => 
    [langcode:protected] => und
    [propertyInfoDefaults:protected] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [getter callback] => entity_property_verbatim_get
            [clear] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [type:protected] => node
    [data:protected] => 
    [info:protected] => Array
        (
            [langcode] => zh-hans
            [type] => node
            [property defaults] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print $wrap->language('zh-hans')->field_main_subtitle->value()
```

Comment: This works, but I thought one of the benefits of entity_metadata_wrapper was that you didn't need to hardcode the language when printing fields?